# Find().length finds the element but returns false : cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to check on a condition if an element exists in the descendent DOM elements of a specific selector using the `find()` as below :

```
 cy.get('[data-testid^="country"]')
   .each(($element) =>{
           if(cy.wrap($element).find('[data-testid$ ="state"]').length > 0){
                 cy.log("Yes,element exists")
                 //more actions }
           else{
              cy.log("No element found") }
```

**Issue:** I am always getting executed with the `else` block. When the code iterates through each `$element` and if the descendant element is actually present it still executes the `else` block and if the decendant element is not present the test case is failing.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue

Answer (score 4):

Simply drop the `cy.wrap()` around `$element`.

`$element` is a jQuery object which also has a `.find()` method, and you can test it's length to find out if the element exists.

```js
cy.get('selector_one')
  .each($element => {
    if ($element.find('another_selector').length > 0) {
      cy.log("Element exists")
      //more actions 
    } else {
      cy.log("No element found") 
    }
  })
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but failing everytime even if the element is actually present in the DOM. It is always executing the else block

Comment: FYI : I am using regular expressions for `selector_one` and `another_selector`. (just in case if it makes any difference like `('[data-testid $="state"]')`

Comment: @user please update the question with the exact selector. The one you show in the comment doesn't look right - the space before `$` is not usually present in examples, and may be causing the problem.

Comment: Edited the question to include actual selectors

Answer (score -2):

The reason why you are always in false block is that Cypress returns a command object but you need to get a DOM element or jQuery object. That's why Cypress is not able to get the length of it.

Try modifying your code this way:

```
 cy.get('parent_selector').each(($element) => {
      cy.wrap($element).find('another_selector').then(($childEl) => {
        if ($childEl.length > 0) {
          cy.log("Element exists");
        } else {
          cy.log("Element doesn't exist");
        }
      });
    });
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Does not really make any sense - how does it get passed the first should?

Comment: No, this did not work for me. When there is no element found it fails to execute

Comment: @user You're right, my bad. I've updated my answer so .then() command executes  based on the fact the element was found or not. If it works for you please remove -1  reaction to answer.

Comment: @Valeriia sorry, but this did not work either.